# Issue with the placementTransform option in the Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to load a PDF document in the Autodesk Viewer with a certain rotation angle. For that, I'm passing the placementTransform option to the loadDocumentNode method. The PDF document is being loaded, no errors whatsoever, but it totally ignores the rotation.
See below how I am creating the rotation matrix and passing it to the loadDocumentNode:

```
            var Rmat = new THREE.Matrix4();
            Rmat.makeRotationX(270);
            showOptions.placementTransform = Rmat;

            if (initialLoad) {
                viewer.startWithDocumentNode(doc, items[pageNumber - 1], showOptions).then(function (loaded) {
                    loadExtensionsWithPromise.call(that, viewer, resolve, reject);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error loading model: ' + error);
                    reject();
                });
            }
            else {
                viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, items[pageNumber - 1], showOptions).then(function (loaded) {
                    loadExtensionsWithPromise.call(that, viewer, resolve, reject);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error loading model: ' + error);
                    reject();
                });
            }
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment that makeRotationX() expects the angle in radian, which would be "Math.PI * 1.5" in your case. 
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Matrix4.makeRotationX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `placementTransform` is definitely the right way of transforming (incl. rotating) the 2D/3D model being loaded. The viewer uses a custom loader for PDF files so it's possible that there's a bug or a missing feature there. We've contacted the engineering team and will report back when we get a response from them.